# Access Transport Layer Secured Windows Communication Service from Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, ssl

I am trying to access transport layer secured wcf service using self signed certificates from asp.net website from ajax.I have tested the service using https protocol in console application and it works fine.It is returning value without any errors.When I try to access the same service from jquery ajax, the error occurs stating that the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed). I do not why and i have read many blogs but could not solve the problem.

Below is my WCF Service code along with config file:

**WCF Service Code:**

**Interface Code:**

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

    namespace EmployeeService
    {
        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]    
        public interface IEmployeeService
        {

            [OperationContract]
            string ShowName(string name);
        }
    }
```

**Class Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using EmployeeLibrary;

namespace EmployeeService
{
   [System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
       public string ShowName(string name)
       {
           EmployeeController controller = new EmployeeController();
           return controller.ShowName(name);
       }
    }
}
```

**WCF Web.config File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EmployeeService.EmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="SecureEmployeeServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EmployeeService.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeService.IEmployeeService" bindingConfiguration="SecureEmployeeServiceBinding">
          <!--<identity>
            <certificate encodedValue=""/>
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="wh"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="EmployeeService.IEmployeeService" bindingConfiguration="wssecureHttpsBinding" />
        <!--<host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>-->
      </service>      
    </services>    
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureEmployeeServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" allowCookies="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows">
              <!--<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Always"></extendedProtectionPolicy>-->
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wssecureHttpsBinding" allowCookies="true" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureEmployeeServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="secureservicewcfserver.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="Online" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="false"/>
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>      
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EmployeeService.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With the above config and code,when i try to access the service from console application,it works fine and return results.

Below is my Console application code with config file:

**console Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SecuredWCFServiceConsoleConsumerApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EmployeeServices.EmployeeServiceClient client = new EmployeeServices.EmployeeServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService");
            string myName = client.ShowName("Shrawan");
            Console.WriteLine(myName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>

        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" openTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>

          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingSecure" openTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/wh"
              binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService"
              contract="EmployeeServices.IEmployeeService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="clientSideSecureWCF">
            <identity>
              <dns value="secureservicewcfserver.com"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/wh"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingSecure"
              contract="EmployeeServices.IEmployeeService" name="webHttpBindingSecure_Service" behaviorConfiguration="clientSideSecureWCF">
            <identity>
              <dns value="secureservicewcfserver.com"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="clientSideSecureWCF">
            <clientCredentials>
              <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="SecuredWCFServiceClient"/>
              <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now when i try to access the same service from asp.net web application using jquery ajax, errror occurs stating that the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Below is my web application code with config file:

**Web Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="SecureWCFServiceWebClient.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #lblServiceOutput {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: chocolate;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: 'https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/ShowName', // Location of the service
                data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Shrawan Lakhe" }), //Data sent to server
                contentType: 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
                dataType: 'jsonp', //Expected data format from server
                processdata: true, //True or False
                success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call
                    debugger
                    var name = data;
                    $('#lblServiceOutput').text(name);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    debugger// When Service call fails
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divServiceResult">
        This is the test application for WCF Secure Application.
        <label id="lblServiceOutput"></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.config Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" openTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingSecure" openTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/wh"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService"
          contract="EmployeeServices.IEmployeeService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEmployeeService" behaviorConfiguration="clientSideSecureWCF">
        <identity>
          <dns value="secureservicewcfserver.com"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="https://secureservicewcfserver.com/EmployeeService.svc/wh"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingSecure"
          contract="EmployeeServices.IEmployeeService" name="webHttpBindingSecure_Service" behaviorConfiguration="clientSideSecureWCF">
        <identity>
          <dns value="secureservicewcfserver.com"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientSideSecureWCF">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="SecuredWCFServiceClient"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any help regarding the solution to this problem will be highly appreciated.Do i need to host both wcf service and web application using secure socket layer and if yes how do i do it? **Thanks**

Comment: `contentType: 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8',` should be `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: Nope that did not work.I did try that.Do you have anything workable solution regarding this problem? If yes, plz post.

Comment: Are you checking this in a custom domain or in Localhost ?

Comment: I have hosted both the service and web application in my local iis and while hosting the service in iis i have give hostname secureservicewcfserver.com which is just for testing purpose and is local and modified the hosts file in system32 with above url..Am i doing something wrong?Plz help...